# How do i display images from database using image URL using HTML?

Tags: html

As i'm doing one small project in that i want to retrieve my images which i stored into my database and passed those images into my local destination up-to this i tried and i did not get my expected output i need some one suggestion i don't whats wrong i did can any one help me.

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript file upload</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>
<body>


  <fieldset>
    <legend>Upload photo</legend>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    <hr>
    <img src="{{url_for('static',filename='static/file/{{row[7]}}')}}">
  </fieldset>


</body>
</html>
```

My Expected Output is:

[image]

Comment: First you need to create web-service/web page that convert your binary data(image data from DB) to image and using that webservice you can display image to web-page.  Sample link if you are using  php  : https://www.codexworld.com/store-retrieve-image-from-database-mysql-php/

Comment: you could convert it to a Base64 string, and then revert it when you want to display it - then it is basically just working with Chars

Comment: while uploading images i will saved it to my local destination i want to retrieve it using img src url path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah., I got my output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript file upload</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>
<body>


  <fieldset>
    <legend>Upload photo</legend>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    <hr>
    <img src="{{url_for('static',filename='static/file/{{row[7]}}')}}">
  </fieldset>


</body>
</html>
```

Here "{{row[7]}}" i have my path of saved images i just retrieved it and displayed.